# How can I variablize a string in HTML?

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring

I have created a JSP where the user can select primary, secondary, tertiary, etc colors and they are saved to the DB. The header and footer JSPs have a hardcoded background-color.

What I would like to do is somehow pull the color string from the database and use that for the background color instead of keeping it hard coded.

I am using Java and Spring on the back-end.

Comment: What attempts have you made?

Comment: You will need to show what you have tried, and only then people can help you out. Just stating your problem here won't help you much other than getting a few downvotes.

Comment: I apologize for not adding more information, I thought it would be a more generic answer due to my lack of specific knowledge. I have posted what my solution was below.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make the string a variable by using JSTL and getting the attribute that was in session.

```
<style>
    .navbar-static-top {
        background: ${client.style.colorPri};
        min-height: 60px;
        border-bottom:0;
    }
...
<style>
```